# What format to pass to printf to convert seconds to hh:mm:ss?

Tags: printf

I'm looking at an instruction of the form:

```
$ printf [format] $elapsed
```

with `$elapsed` expressed in seconds. I want it to output 'hh:mm:ss'. I couldn't figure out `format` from the [man](https://ss64.com/bash/printf.html). Would someone please make a suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

With the `printf` builtin of the ksh93 shell, and assuming `$elapsed` is less than 86400 (one day) that would be:

```
TZ=UTC0 printf '%(%T)T\n' "#$elapsed"
```

Or with the `printf` builtin of recent versions of the bash shell (which has copied a subset of ksh93's feature in an incompatible way):

```
TZ=UTC0 printf '%(%T)T\n' "$elapsed"
```

`%(strftime-format)T` is a ksh93 extension that consumes one argument which is interpreted as a timestamp and formats it as per the `strftime()` format specification, where `%T` short for `%H:%M:%S` gives the time of day in HH:MM:SS 24-hour format. `ksh93` handles all sorts of different timestamp formats including `#number` for Unix epochtime while `bash` handles only numbers which are interpreted as Unix epoch time except for `-1` interpreted as *now* and `-2` interpreted as the time the shell was invoked.

With the `zsh` shell and its `strftime` builtin:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
TZ=UTC0 strftime %T $elapsed
```

With GNU or busybox `date`:

```
date -ud "@$elapsed" +%T
```

Those basically interpret `$elapsed` as an Unix epoch time, the number of Unix seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, hence the `TZ=UTC0` and `-u` to get the corresponding UTC time on that January 1st 1970.

BTW, [the man page you link to](https://ss64.com/bash/printf.html) seems to try (and fail) to document a mix between the GNU `printf` implementation and the `printf` builtin of `bash`, the GNU shell (two not fully compatible implementations of the standard `printf` utility), I wouldn't trust that site.

Run `man printf` *on your system* to get the man page of *your* standalone `printf` utility¹, or `info bash printf` or `info zsh printf` or the man page of *your* shell if neither zsh nor bash for the documentation of its `printf` builtin if it has one (most shells do).

---

<sup>¹ Beware though that if run from within the `fish` shell, `man printf` will give you the man page for fish's `printf` builtin.</sup>

Comment: Thx, what's the logic behind '%(%T)T'?

Comment: @Erwann, see edit. Have you tried `info bash printf`?